# How to get the key of an array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dojo

Given a JSON respond to a form I need to parse through the JSON elements to find error messages with their associated element the error is tied to.

The data is returned in JSON format with the error messages as the last variable pair looking like this:

```
"invalid":[{"field1":"Field 1 is required"}]
```

This ends up having an object/array for each error showing the item's name(key) along with the associated error for that field. Given that my error handling form is unaware what the key names will be how do I go about getting both the key and the value out of this object/array?

I'm using dojo on this project and I'm not familiar with it at all so I've been attempting to use dojo functions when possible if something exists that can handle this. Currently there is where I am :

```
var retObj = dojo.fromJson(ioargs.xhr.responseText);

dojo.forEach(retObj.invalid, function(entry,i){ 
    console.debug(entry);
});
```

The console output is:

```
Object { field1="Field 1 is required"}
```

My goal is to pull out the value "field1" so I know which input field this error is assigned to, then to assign the value of field1 to that error field.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a plethora of questions on SO about parsing JSON.

Comment: what does `console.debug(entry)` output?

Comment: You're already iterating over the elements of the array, so I think your question is not about arrays. I would search on "how to retrieve the properties (or keys) of an object (or associative array)". E.g. see http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html. E.g. put `for (var key in entry) {... entry[key] ...}` inside your function that you pass to forEach.

Comment: I've added the console output. I understand there are dozens of questions on parsing JSON and hundreds about arrays. Unfortunately none of them seem to explain how to grab the key name and value if neither are known. I know the object exists but not the values of them when they come through to me in the JSON. I assume I need to iterate through them but I can't find the keyword or function that allows me to say do : element['key'] and it returns the key value for that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno a single thing about Dojo, but you're looking for a pretty basic `for in` loop.

```
var retObj = dojo.fromJson(ioargs.xhr.responseText),
    invalids = retObj.invalid[0],
    res = {}; //here will be your final key=>value

for (var key in invalids) {
    res[key] = invalids[key];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DgXkq/

You might also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5Dparsing+json

Comment: This is super close to what I'm looking for, but how do I get the key name. In your fiddle example it returns the value for each key, but not the key name. In my case the keyname is actually the id for input the error belongs to. So I need to be able to grab the key's name to know where to put the value for that key. Hopefully this makes sense? It's a complicated question to ask since I'm sure there's a specific word for this.

Comment: In the for in loop, `key` is the key name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to find the key of an object if you don't have access to the parent object. I believe the best solution in this case would be to massage the JSON to pass more meaningful information to the validator, that is, an object with two properties, fieldName and errorMessage.

```
// Returns the name of an object's first key 
function getKeyName(obj) {
   for (var prop in obj) {
       return prop;
   }
}

// This is the response from the server
var response = { "invalid":[{"field1":"Field 1 is required"}] };

// This is going to be the massaged array that
// contains more meaningful information.
var invalids = [];
for (var i=0; i < response.invalid.length; i++) {
  var obj = response.invalid[i];
  var key = getKeyName(obj);
  invalids.push({fieldName: key, errorMessage: obj[key]})
}
```

Now `invalids` contains an array of more meaningful error message objects like
`invalids = [{fieldName: 'field1', errorMessage: 'Field 1 is required'}]`
Just pass that object to your validation routine. If possible, I would change the server code to return error messages in the format I suggested so you don't have to do extra work.